# Espresso click on drawable

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I am trying to click on a drawable which is inside a RecyclerView.
Steps.
1. Swipe Left to open drawable/delete icon.
2. Click on the the drawable

I am able to swipe on the recyclerView item, but i have no idea on how to click on the trash.[image]

Here is my method to swipe left.

```
  public void swipeLeftToDelete(int position) {
        ViewInteraction recyclerView5 = Espresso.onView(
                allOf(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.myRecyclerView),
                        childAtPosition(
                                withClassName(is("android.widget.LinearLayout")),
                                position)));
        recyclerView5.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(position, swipeLeft()));
    }

private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the id for the "bin" icon? Or do you know its view class?

Comment: I have this R.drawable.ic_trash_big , i'm not sure if thats what you are asking for.

Comment: Close. that'd be your resource drawable, resource id looks something like `R.id.myRecyclerView`. Or if you know the view classes that'd be great too. Knowing these views plays important part in Espresso.

Comment: did you resolve this test? I have the same issue